# Array elements (MovieClips) are being deleted as I add new ones. Why?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm having trouble with some odd behavior in ActionScript 2.0. I'm trying to add a certain number of pages (MovieClips) to the stage, and at the same time store references to the in a convenient array for later access. Here is my code (assume all variables have been properly declared):

```
    _adPages = new Array();

    _adPages[0] = adPageTrack.attachMovie("adPage", "adpage0" + 0, getNextHighestDepth());
    _adPages[0].init( _adItems[0] );
    _adPages[0]._x = 0 * 10;

    _adPages[1] = adPageTrack.attachMovie("adPage", "adpage0" + 1, getNextHighestDepth());
    _adPages[1].init( _adItems[1] );
    _adPages[1]._x = 1 * 10;

    _adPages[2] = adPageTrack.attachMovie("adPage", "adpage0" + 2, getNextHighestDepth());
    _adPages[2].init( _adItems[2] );
    _adPages[2]._x = 2 * 10;

    _adPages[3] = adPageTrack.attachMovie("adPage", "adpage0" + 3, getNextHighestDepth());
    _adPages[3].init( _adItems[3] );
    _adPages[3]._x = 3 * 10;

    trace(_adPages);
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        trace("Ad page x coordinate: " + _adPages[i]._x);
        trace("Ad page y coordinate: " + _adPages[i]._y);
    }
```

This was originally a loop, it has been exploded so I can examine it more closely. Note the trace statements. They should output an array of MovieClip handles, followed by a list of x and y coordinates. Instead, they output this:

```
,,,_level0.main.adPageTrack.adpage03
Ad page x coordinate: undefined
Ad page y coordinate: undefined
Ad page x coordinate: undefined
Ad page y coordinate: undefined
Ad page x coordinate: undefined
Ad page y coordinate: undefined
Ad page x coordinate: 30
Ad page y coordinate: 0
```

Where all but the last item to be set up have been deleted. If I delete the fourth item, then the third item is now intact while all others disappear.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Is this a bug or am I just missing something about the language?

Comment: This looks pretty correct, are you sure its safe to "assume all variables have been properly declared"?

Comment: Yep. I've gone through and checked each one twice at this point.

Comment: Where have you defined `_adPages[i]._y`?

Comment: _adPages is defined higher up on the page, outside of this code. It is then filled with MovieClips, which all have y coordinates. That's basically it.

Comment: if the movieClips all have a y-coordinate then are they already on the stage? it looks like you are referring to the same movieClip (adPage) several times (not creating a new instance of the adPage movieClip but attempting to use the same one multiple times. could this be the issue? or does attachMovie actually create a new movieClip?

Comment: Maybe adPageTrack.getNextHighestDepth()?

Comment: that is just a this statement so it's not necessary to call the full thing. but maybe try this. getNextHighestDepth(); just in case? I know that attachMovie is supposed to create a new movieClip instance each time, but it just looks like it's not doing that. try tracing _adPages after you define each movieClip. what happens then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use adPageTrack.getNextHighestDepth() when you attach the movieclip otherwise every attachMovie call erase the previous one.

```
_adPages[0] = adPageTrack.attachMovie("adPage", "adpage0" + 0, adPageTrack.getNextHighestDepth());
[...]
```